# Extract text in string until certain new line ("\n")

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, macos

I have a long text in python. It consists of 20 rows. Is there any way I can get the text up until a certain row?

Let's say that the text is called text_variable.

I would the like to be able to do something like

```
first_seven_rows = text_variable[:row 7]
```

`print(first_seven_rows)` should then return the first seven lines of the text.

Could this maybe be done with regex? How do I specify that I want regex to extract everything up until the seventh "\n"?

I hope you understand my question.

Comment: Yes, if you've read in the file into `text_variable`, then `first_seven_rows = text_variable[:7]` will do the trick.

Comment: Won't that only extract the first seven characters? I want to extract the first seven rows of the text.

Comment: You should really ask another question, but be exact with what `text` you have. Give an example. Anyway, perhaps you want: `first_seven_rows = text_variable.split()[:7]`